# Configure Sharepoint Search for web application with multiple site collections

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search-results, enterprise-search

I have a web application with around 40 site collections each with its own content database.now i want to configure a search service that would retrieve search result from all of the site collections.
How do i go about it?
Also,is it possible that search happens in a particular list/library instead of searching all the lists and libraries??

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are working with SharePoint 2013.
For the first question to configure all site collection for search you need to **create a content source** under which you will specify the content to be crawled from.
[To create a content source you can this link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/step-to-configure-search-service-in-sharepoint-2013-part-two/)

And for second question to search happens in a particular list/library instead of all list and libraries.

There are two way to do so:-

1. First one is creating a **result source** and specifying the query to return content from specific list only. For creating a content source with query

   {searchTerms} http://siteName/Lists/ListA(contentclass:STS_ListItem_GenericList)
2. And the second option is to uncheck the option appear in search option in list setting --> Adnvance setting -->`Allow items from this list to appear in search results?`